Clone Kubuntu to different computer, different hardware
Slowly I am trying to keep a promise I made myself years ago, to get off Windows (and anything Microsoft) as soon as feasible.  I've only one last (unfortunately, critical) application I have to run there, and won't run correctly in Wine, but I have begun the migration. I only need to keep one Windows box.
I had Mint in the past and liked it, but decided to try Kubuntu, so I installed it on my weakest box, an iBuyPower.  It's been working great, and spent a lot of hours configuring and getting my mouse remapped and another couple devices and software working as desired.
Now I want to clone the whole thing over to my best computer, without spending all the time configuring.  I know there are some other topics on this site similar to my question, but I didn't really see simple answers; I'm effectively a newbie on Linux.
I don't really mind installing Kubuntu on the other machine, if that is the best method to get it configured to the new hardware, but after that I would like to copy over my entire configuration, so I will not need to customize the environment, or install and customize software / drivers (the new machine will use the same USB devices as this one, through a KVM).
These are the specs Kubuntu lists for the original iBuyPower system:
   OS: Kubuntu 24.04
   KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
   KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
   Qt Version: 5.15.13
   Kernel Version: 6.8.0-51-generic (64-bit)
   Graphics Platform: X11
   CPU: 6 × AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
   RAM: 15.6 GiB
   Graphics Processor: NV137
   Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
   Product Name: GA-78LMT-S2
...And these are the specs CPU-Z lists for the Windows 10 system I will either be deleting or creating a dual boot:
   Motherboard: Gigabyte X570 AORUS MASTER
   Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5500, 3600 Mhz, 6 core
   RAM: 64 GB DDR4
   Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050i
   Storage devices: 2 SSDs, 2 HDDs
Is the best way to seamlessly accomplish this through Clonezilla, or just install Kubuntu and dd over the file structure, or rsync or something else entirely?
Once I figure out the best solution, I can probably research more detail about how to use it correctly, but please keep in mind I am a pretty much a novice with Linux.  I saw recommendations for SystemImager (which looked pretty complicated to me, TBH), and Clonezilla, which may be simpler...(?)  But I welcome all suggestions.
Also, should I decide to create a dual boot Windows/Linux, I'd welcome any hints about that too (though I can probably just google it).  If I go that route, I'd probably just buy a new NVMe SSD, in which case I would not be able to configure it inside the old machine (no NVMe slots).

Do you have a NAS device? The approach here is to create a copy of /home/<your username> on the NAS device as most settings are stored as hidden dot files and dot directories in your /home/ folder. After you've copied your home directory to the NAS, reinstall KUbuntu, create a new user with the same username you stored on the NAS, and then copy it back, making sure to replace existing files, then change the owner of the directory so the GID and UID match again.

Do not use dd (may break gpt), you can use rsync to copy /home or data partition(s). Really should have good backup of /home, settings in /etc you may have edited, and list of installed apps. Then new install just requires restore of backup & reinstall of apps. Be sure to use gpt partitioning, UEFI install for any system in last 10 years.

@user68186 whilst there are a myriad of ways, I don't think that means the answers are opinion based, necessarily. It's a good question imo, one for which answers could find broad use.

Are you looking to copy the installation to another system, i.e. run the same installation on two systems? Or do you just want to migrate, i.e. only use the installation on the destination system? In the first case, there are issues that may bite you in the future with data that should be unique per installation. Two things that spring to my mind are filesystem UUIDs, and SSH host keys.

Whilst i know you’ve had some answers that probably achieve what you’re trying to do, I’d urge you not to do this. Your installation will (if LTS) last you years; there may well be subtle performance issues if some of your configurations aren’t quite right if you just copy from an installation on a different machine. A small number of hours installing from scratch and configuring it exactly as you want is probably time well spent in my view.

First you need to get a list of the packages from your custom installation, and then use it to install this list directly into your new installation. To do this, run in a terminal:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dselect
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > kubuntu-files

This generates kubuntu-files, which contains the list of installed programs.
Once the new installation is complete, take this file to the new machine and you will have all the programs installed by running:
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo dpkg --set-selections < kubuntu-files
 sudo dselect install

This will only reinstall your favorite applications.
To have your settings, you must copy the contents of /home/user/ to a USB with sufficient capacity using the file manager and restore it, overwriting the directories once the installation is finished.
---- Edited ----
To install, try the following.
Start a Live Kubuntu session on new pc
The upload is complete.
Open a terminal.
Run on it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted, select the SDD or HD and create a new gpt partition table and the following partitions:
One 1 gb Efi System
One 100 gb, ext4 for /
One   8 gb, swap for Swap or triple the RAM,
One of the remaining gigs, ext4 for /home
Apply the changes
Start the installation and in partitioning choose manual.
And select the partitions for / and for /home, Grub is installed by default
Use Kubuntu 24.04.1 which is LTS, https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/24.04.1/release/kubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Thank you; this might work well.  Does /home/user/ contain settings for both installed software and KDE desktop?  Also, when you say "perform the installation using Gparted from a live session", you mean run gparted from the new machine after kubuntu install?

Yes and NO. Yes, it contains all the settings for /home/user/. No, Gparted does, from a live session, prior to installation. I edit the post to clarify.

While there are ways to backup and restore KDE configurations, your need for software, software settings, and drivers are pushing me to suggest Clonezilla.
But I would simply move the HDD/SSD that is currently in the old machine into the new one to test your current configuration on your destination hardware. You'll need both disks in the same machine for a simple Clonezilla operation anyway.
If that works, and you still want your new setup running on one of your other (presumably newer/faster) disks, then boot into Clonezilla and clone it to the new disk.
Note: I believe Clonezilla requires the target disk to be larger than the source disk.

Thank you, will look more into the Clonezilla docs.

Putting a old disk with an installed Linux systemn into a new computer is usually no problem and a cloned disk should also work. There are a few things to consider:

If you're using hardware that needs non-free drivers it may start in fallback mode (e.g. when Nvidia-Drivers need to be installed) and you need to install the drivers to be able to fully use the system
You may need to change device-ids that are different. /dev/sdX may be enumerated in a different order, hardware UUIDs will be different, etc.
If you want to have both disks in the same PC you also need to avoid duplicate UUIDs, this means after cloning you need to set a new UUID (and possibly label) on filesystems that have one, otherwise mounting by filesystem UUID may fail and other programs that use the UUID so they don't depend on the order of the sdX device will get confused as well.
Do you want to duplicate your /home or migrate it? Most things are no problem to be duplicated, but you may for example end up with two computers with almost the same Firefox profile, but all new bookmarks that were created after the cloning being different. Also some programs may need to have changed machine IDs (e.g. Firefox sync, Filesync tools like dropbox, etc.) to be able to distinguish between the PCs.
Maybe you also like a fresh start and install things a different way than on the old PCs. Especially when the hardware is more powerful you may want to use features that you disabled on the old PC for performance reasons.

Setting filesystem (UU)IDs:
On standard ext2/3/4 filesystems you can use tune2fs -U with either a specific UUID, random, or time to set the filesystem UUID. A random UUID should be fine. You can also set a human readable label with tune2fs -L but then you need to manually take care not to have two partitions with the same label.

Thank you.  I'm not sure how to change device UUIDs, but I can figure that out.

On standard ext2/3/4 filesystems you can use tune2fs -U for that.
